# How do I find a canonical basis for A?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: question]

I know how to find the JFC but I don't know what's a canonical basis for A. Can someone explain?

Comment: $A$ is similar to its Jordan canonical form, i.e. there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is in Jordan form.  Conjugation by $P$ means you are changing the basis of your vector space.  So I think it's asking what is the new basis?

Comment: @D_S : That would have made an excellent Answer.

Comment: You mean the basis for PAP^-1 ?

Comment: No, the basis for $P$.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is the matrix that represents a linear transformation in the standard basis: $\{(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\}$.

The canonical basis for the same linear transformation is the basis in which the transformation is expressed by a matrix in the Jordan canonical form. This basis  is made by the proper and generalized eigenvectors of the tranformation.

In your case these vectors are: $\{(-1,0,1)^T,(1,0,0)^T,(2,1,0)^T\}$and we have:

$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&-1\\
0&2&0\\
1&-2&3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&1&2\\
0&0&1\\
1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
1&-2&1\\
0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
=SJS^{-1}
$$

Comment: is this singular value decomposition (SVD)?